# Data on unallocated space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

Earlier, on a [separate question](https://superuser.com/questions/695514/testdisk-photorec-to-get-back-data-from-unallocated-partition), I was trying to recover data from a lost partition. Specifically, the partition was lost from a Windows 7 NTFS partition, and is now unallocated space. Through Photorec and Testdisk, I can still see the data, and I think I can recover it.
How can the space be identified by gparted as unallocated when there's data there? Can a filesystem labeled unallocated still contain data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How Unallocated Space is Identified

Allocated space (partitions) and unallocated space is identified by reading the partition table contained on disk. In the case of an MBR partition scheme, the entries for partitions are stored in bytes 446 - 511 of your hard disk.

In general, each partition entry contains the offset and length, as well as the type of the partition. For instance, the following could be MBR entries on a hypothetical 12288 byte (12 KB!) hard disk:

```
+==================================+
| ID |   Offset |   Length |  Type |
|====+==========+==========+=======|
|  1 |      512 |     1024 |  NTFS |
|  2 |     1536 |     1536 |  NTFS |
|  3 |     6144 |     6144 |  ext4 |
+==================================+
```

In the given example, there are 3 partitions. The first partition occupies offsets 512 - 1536. The second partition occupies offsets 1536 - 3072. The third partition occupies offsets 6144 - 12288.

From here, it is observable that offsets 3072 - 6144 is not occupied by any partition and is hence identified as unallocated space.

### Can a filesystem labeled unallocated still contain data?

Well, a filesystem labeled unallocated is not a filesystem anymore (;

Regions identified as unallocated can still contain data - most partition deletion tools nowadays (`gparted` included, I think) do not erase the entire region occupied by a partition when you delete the partition. Typically, only the corresponding entry in the partition table is removed, and data that stays in the region remains there until a new filesystem is created on it.

Testdisk relies on this fact by scanning the entire disk (as opposed to just reading the partition table) for special signatures (a sequence of bytes that uniquely identifies a partition) to locate lost partitions on disk.